# Getting list of results not contained in same list with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Lets say I have a list of `ToFilter` objects that look as follows:

```
private class ToFilter {
    String option1;
    String option2;
}
```

Using Java streams I want to filter out all elements where option 1 is not contained in any other object's option 2. So for example if there are 4 instances of ToFilter with:

```
option1 = C,
option2 = A

option1 = C,
option2 = F

option1 = A,
option2 = B

option1 = A,
option2 = D
```

C should be filtered and contained in the result set because it has entries in `option1` but not `option2` of any other object. Something like the `nonematch()`, but that actually returns a list of `ToFilter` objects rather than just a boolean true.

Comment: Is it required to compare `option1` values to `option2` values on **different** `ToFilter` entries only? i.e., is it expected that a `ToFilter` object can have the same value for `option1` and `option2`?

Comment: Hi, @ernest_k, thanks for your interest! In my case option 1 and 2 will never be the same for a singular ToFilter object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two streams, creating a set of all `option2` values against which I check `option1` values from the collection:

```
List<ToFilter> list = ...;

Set<String> option2Set = list.stream()
        .map(ToFilter::getOption2)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<ToFilter> filtered = list.stream()
        .filter(f -> !option2Set.contains(f.getOption1()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This seems to be better regarding performance than some of the other solutions: It iterates only exactly twice over all entries.

Comment: This won’t work, because it doesn’t differentiate between option 2 in the same object and other objects. ie if an object has the same option 1 and option 2, and no other object has that option 2, it will get filtered out, but it shouldn’t because only it should only get filtered out if *another* object has that option 2. You’re on the right track though, but you need a different data structure than a set to store option 2s

Comment: @Bohemian That may be valid. I didn't understand it as option2 values would have to be searched on *other* entries (which would then assume option2 can be set to the same value as option1 on the same `ToFilter` object). Will have to ask OP to clarify

Comment: @ernest_k no need to ask; it’s clear and unambiguous in the question: *I want to filter out all elements where option 1 is not contained in any other object's option 2*

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use [`Stream.noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) here as:

```
List<ToFilter> finalResult = filterList.stream()
        .filter(a -> filterList.stream() // use filter if same object could have option 1 and 2 equal
                .noneMatch(toFilter -> a.getOption1().equals(toFilter.getOption2()))) 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You need to put in `if (!a.equals(toFilter))` your `noneMatch`.
Also you need to add a map at the end `.map(a -> a.getOption1())`.
OP wanted only the letters, otherwise it looks good.

Comment: @fastcodejava Well, the question read *but that actually returns a list of ToFilter objects rather than just a boolean true* and I am sure that OP wanted `C A`, `C F` as the output. Thanks :)